# Lodash or Javascript decorator for all functions in object

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

For below object

```
const ourObject = {
    func1: (arg1, arg2, arg3) => arg3
    func2: (arg1) => void
};

ourFunction(ourObject);

ourObject.func1(1,2,3);
```

after above I would like to log arguments and return output of func1, so I believe need to iterate thru all fields and then use something like below

```
console.log(argmuments)
return func.apply(arguments)
```

does lodash already have solution for it?

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking. So you want to basically override all of the methods in an object and log the arguments?

Comment: Are you looking for a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)?

Answer (score 0):

So loop over the keys, make a copy, define a new method, reference the arguments, and call the original method.

```js
const ourObject = {
  func1: (arg1, arg2, arg3) => arg3,
  func2: (arg1) => 'bar'
}

// Loop over the keys of the object
Object.keys(ourObject).forEach((key) => {
  // copy the original method
  const org = ourObject[key]
  // create the new method
  ourObject[key] = function(...args) {
    // log the arguments
    console.log(key, args)
    // call the original
    return org.apply(this, args)
  }
})

console.log(ourObject.func1(1, 2, 3))
console.log(ourObject.func2('foo'))
```

Comment: Guessing showing how to iterate over the fields is wrong?

Comment: Don't know why that got downvoted.  I was in the middle of answering the question and pretty much had the same strategy.

Comment: No Lodash? Just a guess, though. In all honesty, OP's question isn't very clear this *might* be the solution but I'm not really sure.

Comment: Since I have swapped to ES6/7 with my code, I have dropped lodah/jQuery. Things I used it for are not in the core so why add extra baggage. Someone can add an answer with `_.keys` and forEach, but it is basically the same thing.